# Difference between getGenericParameterTypes and getParameterTypes

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to learn the difference between `getGenericParameterTypes` and `getParameterTypes` methods. I know that one returns `Class[]` and the other `Type[]`. But what is ther real difference?

Considering methods:

```
public void method1(T arg1)
public void method2(String arg2)
```

What would I get when invoking each of the `get` methods over each of the example methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't exactly tell you what you would get, but one difference is that for method 2 you can tell the parameter type is `Class<String>` whereas for method 1 you'd just know there's a parameter named `T`, but you don't know the exact type except the class where `T` is declared would have been subclassed with a concrete class for `T`.

Example:

```
class Foo<T> {
   public void method1( T arg1 ) { ... }
}

class Bar extends Foo<Baz> { ... }

Foo<?> foo = new Foo<Baz>();
Bar bar = new Bar();
```

For `foo` you'd not be able to get the type of `T` at runtime (you'd not know it's `Baz`) nor at compile time. For `bar` you'd be able to get the type for `T` since it is already known at compile time.

Another difference when looking at the code:

Calling `getGenericParameterTypes()` on method 1 should return the `T` type, calling it for method 2 should return `Class<String>`. However, if you call `getTypeParameters()` you'd get the `T` type for method 1 but a zero-length array for method 2.

Edit: since `getParameterTypes()` was meant instead of `getTypeParameters()` here's the difference I can see from the code:

For method 2 there would be no difference, since if no Generics are used in the signature, `getGenericParameterTypes()` actually calls `getParameterTypes()`.  For method 1 `getGenericParameterTypes()` would return a `ParameterizedType` that states the parameter has name `T` whereas `getParameterTypes()` would return the required base class of the type, e.g. `Class<Object>` for `<T>` or `Class<Number>` for `<T extends Number>`.

Comment: I am sorry, I've made a mistake. I meant `getParameterTypes` and not `getTypeParameters`. There is a difference. I hardly noticed. Could you edit your answer to reflex this change?

Answer (score 6):

`getGenericParameterTypes` can return other kind of `Type`s. `getParameterType` is the "pre-generics" reflection. This means `T` will be considered as `java.lang.Object`. Check this example:

```
public class Generics<T> {

    public void method1(T t) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method m = Generics.class.getMethod("method1", Object.class);
        for (Type t : m.getGenericParameterTypes()) {
            System.out.println("with GPT: " + t);
        }
        for (Type t : m.getParameterTypes()) {
            System.out.println("with PT: " + t);
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
with GPT: T
with PT: class java.lang.Object
```