# In around avice, how to get the 'type parameter' of a parameter of the advised method

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-aop, type-parameter

With Spring AOP, I am writing an Aspect with an around advice that intercepts any method annotated with `@MyAnnotation`. Suppose the intercepted method was declared as follows,

```
@MyAnnotation
public String someMethod(ArrayList<Integer> arrList) {...}
```

In the advice method, I want to get infomation that the first parameter, i.e. `arrList`, has the type `ArrayList` with the type parameter `Integer`.

I have tried following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection) by doing this

```
@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
    Class<?>[] paramsClass = method.getParameterTypes();
    logger.info(((ParameterizedType) paramsClass[0].getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0])
    ...
}
```

But what was logged out is just an `E`. How shoud I do to so that it prints `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860393/java-generics-obtaining-actual-type-of-generic-parameter#19860597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
    Type[] genericParamsClass = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

    logger.info(((ParameterizedType) genericParamsClass[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you have time, please explain what exactly the `method.getGenericParameterTypes()` returns. I have tried to find out what is the different between `class` and `type` and as far as I understand, `type` is the generalization of `class`, and other `type` are `interface`, `array` and `primitive`. But I can't figure out what kind of `type` returned by `method.getGenericParameterTypes()` that can have the information that the generic parameter is `java.lang.Integer`. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747383/difference-between-getgenericparametertypes-and-getparametertypes